# Drag and drop android-ios with KineticJS

Tags: javascript

This is my HTML code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Paint Tool</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://d3lp1msu2r81bx.cloudfront.net/kjs/js/lib/kinetic-v4.7.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Event.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="paint.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="init.js"></script>
  <style>
    body{padding:20px;}
    #container{
      border:solid 3px black;
      margin-top: 10px;
      width:wWidth-20;
      height:wHeight-20;
    }
    #toolbar{
      width:wWidth-20;
      height:wHeight-20;
      border:solid 3px black;
    }
    #toolbar2{
      width:wWidth-20;
      height:wHeight-20;
      border:solid 3px black;
    }
    #toolbar3{
      width:wWidth-20;
      height:wHeight-20;
      border:solid 3px black;
    }
  </style>        
</head>

<body>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  /// Prevent native scrolling in iOS.
  Event.add(document.body, 'touchmove', Event.prevent);   

  /// Prevent right-click on desktops.
  Event.add(document.body, 'contextmenu', Event.prevent);
  </script>
    <div id = "toolbar">
        <img id = "paint" width=52 height=52 src="img/Lapiz Negro-01.png">
        <img id = "paint2" width=52 height=52 src="img/Lapiz Rojo-01.png">
        <img id = "erase" width=52 height=52 src="img/Goma-01.png">
        <img id = "clear" width=52 height=52 src="img/Limpiar-01.png">
        <img id = "size1" width=52 height=52 src="img/Dot Small-01.png">
        <img id = "size2" width=52 height=52 src="img/Dot Medium-01.png">
        <img id = "size3" width=52 height=52 src="img/Dot Big-01.png">   
        <img id = "save" width=52 height=52 src="img/Guardar-01.png"> 
    </div><br>
    <div id="toolbar2">
        <img id="via1"  width=52 height=52 src="img/Cruce1.png">
        <img id="via2" width=52 height=52 src="img/Cruce2.png">
        <img id="via3" width=52 height=52 src="img/Cruce3.png">
        <img id="via4" width=52 height=52 src="img/Cruce4.png">
        <img id="via5" width=52 height=52 src="img/Cruce5.png">
        <img id="via6" width=52 height=52 src="img/Cruce6.png">
        <img id="via7" width=52 height=52 src="img/Cruce7.png">
        <img id="via8" width=52 height=52 src="img/Cruce8.png">
        <img id="via9" width=52 height=52 src="img/Curva1.png">
        <img id="via10" width=52 height=52 src="img/Curva2.png">
        <img id="via11" width=52 height=52 src="img/Curva3.png">
        <img id="via12" width=52 height=52 src="img/Curva4.png">
        <img id="via13" width=52 height=52 src="img/MediaCurva1.png">
        <img id="via14" width=52 height=52 src="img/MediaCurva2.png">
        <img id="via15" width=52 height=52 src="img/MediaCurva3.png">
        <img id="via16" width=52 height=52 src="img/MediaCurva4.png">
        <img id="via17" width=52 height=52 src="img/Recta1.png">
        <img id="via18" width=52 height=52 src="img/Recta2.png">
    </div><br>
    <div id="toolbar3">
        <img id="icon1" width=52 height=52 src="img/Icon1.png">
        <img id="icon2" width=52 height=52 src="img/Icon2.png">
        <img id="icon3" width=52 height=52 src="img/Icon3.png">
        <img id="icon4" width=52 height=52 src="img/Icon4.png">
        <img id="icon5" width=52 height=52 src="img/Icon5.png">
        <img id="icon6" width=52 height=52 src="img/Icon6.png">
        <img id="icon7" width=52 height=52 src="img/Icon7.png">
        <img id="icon8" width=52 height=52 src="img/Icon8.png">
        <img id="icon9" width=52 height=52 src="img/Icon9.png">
        <img id="icon10" width=52 height=52 src="img/Icon10.png">
        <img id="icon11" width=52 height=52 src="img/Icon11.png">
        <img id="icon12" width=52 height=52 src="img/Icon12.png">
        <img id="icon13" width=52 height=52 src="img/Icon13.png">
        <img id="icon14" width=52 height=52 src="img/Icon14.png">
        <img id="icon15" width=52 height=52 src="img/Icon15.png">
    </div><br>
    <div id="container"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is my js code:

```
function init() {
    var wWidth = window.innerWidth - 100;
    var wHeigth = window.innerHeight - 100;
    var color ="black";
    var sizeDraw = 5;
    var _has_touch = ('ontouchstart' in window);

    /** 
      * get a reference to the via in the toolbar
      *hide the via until its image has loaded
      */

    var $via1=$("#via1");
    $via1.hide();
    var $via2=$("#via2");
    $via2.hide();
    var $via3=$("#via3");
    $via3.hide();
    var $via4=$("#via4");
    $via4.hide();
    var $via5=$("#via5");
    $via5.hide();
    var $via6=$("#via6");
    $via6.hide();
    var $via7=$("#via7");
    $via7.hide();
    var $via8=$("#via8");
    $via8.hide();
    var $via9=$("#via9");
    $via9.hide();
    var $via10=$("#via10");
    $via10.hide();
    var $via11=$("#via11");
    $via11.hide();
    var $via12=$("#via12");
    $via12.hide();
    var $via13=$("#via13");
    $via13.hide();
    var $via14=$("#via14");
    $via14.hide();
    var $via15=$("#via15");
    $via15.hide();
    var $via16=$("#via16");
    $via16.hide();
    var $via17=$("#via17");
    $via17.hide();
    var $via18=$("#via18");
    $via18.hide();


    /** 
      * get a reference to the icon in the toolbar
      * hide the icon until its image has loaded
      */

    var $icon1=$("#icon1");
    $icon1.hide();
    var $icon2=$("#icon2");
    $icon2.hide();
    var $icon3=$("#icon3");
    $icon3.hide();
    var $icon4=$("#icon4");
    $icon4.hide();
    var $icon5=$("#icon5");
    $icon5.hide();
    var $icon6=$("#icon6");
    $icon6.hide();
    var $icon7=$("#icon7");
    $icon7.hide();
    var $icon8=$("#icon8");
    $icon8.hide();
    var $icon9=$("#icon9");
    $icon9.hide();
    var $icon10=$("#icon10");
    $icon10.hide();
    var $icon11=$("#icon11");
    $icon11.hide();
    var $icon12=$("#icon12");
    $icon12.hide();
    var $icon13=$("#icon13");
    $icon13.hide();
    var $icon14=$("#icon14");
    $icon14.hide();
    var $icon15=$("#icon15");
    $icon15.hide();

    // get the offset position of the kinetic container
    var $stageContainer=$("#container");
    var stageOffset=$stageContainer.offset();
    var offsetX=stageOffset.left;
    var offsetY=stageOffset.top;

    // create the Kinetic.Stage and layer
    var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
        container: 'container',
        width: wWidth,
        height: wHeigth
    });
    var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
    stage.add(layer);

    var background = new Kinetic.Rect({
            x: 0,
            y: 0,
            width: wWidth+10,
            height: wHeigth+10,
            fill: 'white',
            stroke: 'black',
            strokeWidth: 1,
        })        
        layer.add(background);
        layer.draw();


        // a flag we use to see if we're dragging the mouse
        var isMouseDown=false;
        // a reference to the line we are currently drawing
        var newline;
        // a reference to the array of points making newline
        var points=[];

        // on the background
        // listen for mousedown, mouseup and mousemove events
        background.on('mousedown', function(){onMousedown();});
        background.on('mouseup', function(){onMouseup();});
        background.on('mousemove', function(){onMousemove();});
        background.on('touchstart', function(){onMousedown();});
        background.on('touchend', function(){onMouseup();});
        background.on('touchmove', function(){onMousemove();});

        // On mousedown
        // Set the isMouseDown flag to true
        // Create a new line,
        // Clear the points array for new points
        // set newline reference to the newly created line
        function onMousedown(event) {
            isMouseDown = true;
            points=[];
            points.push(stage.getPointerPosition());
            var line = new Kinetic.Line({
                points: points,
                stroke: color,
                strokeWidth: sizeDraw,
                lineCap: 'round',
                lineJoin: 'round'
            });
            layer.add(line);
            newline=line;
        }

        // on mouseup end the line by clearing the isMouseDown flag
        function onMouseup(event) {
            isMouseDown=false;
        }

        // on mousemove
        // Add the current mouse position to the points[] array
        // Update newline to include all points in points[]
        // and redraw the layer
        function onMousemove(event) {
            if(!isMouseDown){return;};
            points.push(stage.getPointerPosition());
            newline.setPoints(points);
            layer.drawScene();
        }




    // start loading the image used in the draggable toolbar element
    // this image will be used in a new Kinetic.Image

    var image1=new Image();
    image1.onload=function(){
        $via1.show();
    }
    image1.src="img/Cruce1.png";
    var image2=new Image();
    image2.onload=function(){
        $via2.show();
    }
    image2.src="img/Cruce2.png";
    var image3=new Image();
    image3.onload=function(){
        $via3.show();
    }
    image3.src="img/Cruce3.png";
    var image4=new Image();
    image4.onload=function(){
        $via4.show();
    }
    image4.src="img/Cruce4.png";
    var image5=new Image();
    image5.onload=function(){
        $via5.show();
    }
    image5.src="img/Cruce5.png";
    var image6=new Image();
    image6.onload=function(){
        $via6.show();
    }
    image6.src="img/Cruce6.png";
    var image7=new Image();
    image7.onload=function(){
        $via7.show();
    }
    image7.src="img/Cruce7.png";
    var image8=new Image();
    image8.onload=function(){
        $via8.show();
    }
    image8.src="img/Cruce8.png";
    var image9=new Image();
    image9.onload=function(){
        $via9.show();
    }
    image9.src="img/Curva1.png";
    var image10=new Image();
    image10.onload=function(){
        $via10.show();
    }
    image10.src="img/Curva2.png";
    var image11=new Image();
    image11.onload=function(){
        $via11.show();
    }
    image11.src="img/Curva3.png";
    var image12=new Image();
    image12.onload=function(){
        $via12.show();
    }
    image12.src="img/Curva4.png";
    var image13=new Image();
    image13.onload=function(){
        $via13.show();
    }
    image13.src="img/MediaCurva1.png";
    var image14=new Image();
    image14.onload=function(){
        $via14.show();
    }
    image14.src="img/MediaCurva2.png";
    var image15=new Image();
    image15.onload=function(){
        $via15.show();
    }
    image15.src="img/MediaCurva3.png";
    var image16=new Image();
    image16.onload=function(){
        $via16.show();
    }
    image16.src="img/MediaCurva4.png";
    var image17=new Image();
    image17.onload=function(){
        $via17.show();
    }
    image17.src="img/Recta1.png";
    var image18=new Image();
    image18.onload=function(){
        $via18.show();
    }
    image18.src="img/Recta2.png";


    //Icons

    var imgicon1=new Image();
    imgicon1.onload=function(){
        $icon1.show();
    }
    imgicon1.src="img/Icon1.png";
    var imgicon2=new Image();
    imgicon2.onload=function(){
        $icon2.show();
    }
    imgicon2.src="img/Icon2.png";
    var imgicon3=new Image();
    imgicon3.onload=function(){
        $icon3.show();
    }
    imgicon3.src="img/Icon3.png";
    var imgicon4=new Image();
    imgicon4.onload=function(){
        $icon4.show();
    }
    imgicon4.src="img/Icon4.png";
    var imgicon5=new Image();
    imgicon5.onload=function(){
        $icon5.show();
    }
    imgicon5.src="img/Icon5.png";
    var imgicon6=new Image();
    imgicon6.onload=function(){
        $icon6.show();
    }
    imgicon6.src="img/Icon6.png";
    var imgicon7=new Image();
    imgicon7.onload=function(){
        $icon7.show();
    }
    imgicon7.src="img/Icon7.png";
    var imgicon8=new Image();
    imgicon8.onload=function(){
        $icon8.show();
    }
    imgicon8.src="img/Icon8.png";
    var imgicon9=new Image();
    imgicon9.onload=function(){
        $icon9.show();
    }
    imgicon9.src="img/Icon9.png";
    var imgicon10=new Image();
    imgicon10.onload=function(){
        $icon10.show();
    }
    imgicon10.src="img/Icon10.png";
    var imgicon11=new Image();
    imgicon11.onload=function(){
        $icon11.show();
    }
    imgicon11.src="img/Icon11.png";
    var imgicon12=new Image();
    imgicon12.onload=function(){
        $icon12.show();
    }
    imgicon12.src="img/Icon12.png";
    var imgicon13=new Image();
    imgicon13.onload=function(){
        $icon13.show();
    }
    imgicon13.src="img/Icon13.png";
    var imgicon14=new Image();
    imgicon14.onload=function(){
        $icon14.show();
    }
    imgicon14.src="img/Icon14.png";
    var imgicon15=new Image();
    imgicon15.onload=function(){
        $icon15.show();
    }
    imgicon15.src="img/Icon15.png";


    //Creation of listeners for click and touch events.

    $('#erase').get(0).addEventListener('click', function(e) { erase(); }, false);
    $('#clear').get(0).addEventListener('click', function(e) { onReset(); }, false);
    $('#size1').get(0).addEventListener('click', function(e) { onSizeClick(e.target.id); }, false);
    $('#size2').get(0).addEventListener('click', function(e) { onSizeClick(e.target.id); }, false);
    $('#size3').get(0).addEventListener('click', function(e) { onSizeClick(e.target.id); }, false);
    $('#save').get(0).addEventListener('click', function(e) { onSave(); }, false);
    $('#paint').get(0).addEventListener('click', function(e) { paint(); }, false);
    $('#paint2').get(0).addEventListener('click', function(e) { paintRed(); }, false);
    $('#erase').get(0).addEventListener('touchstart', function(e) { erase(); }, false);
    $('#clear').get(0).addEventListener('touchstart', function(e) { onReset(); }, false);
    $('#size1').get(0).addEventListener('touchstart', function(e) { onSizeClick(e.target.id); }, false);
    $('#size2').get(0).addEventListener('touchstart', function(e) { onSizeClick(e.target.id); }, false);
    $('#size3').get(0).addEventListener('touchstart', function(e) { onSizeClick(e.target.id); }, false);
    $('#save').get(0).addEventListener('touchstart', function(e) { onSave(); }, false);
    $('#paint').get(0).addEventListener('touchstart', function(e) { paint(); }, false);
    $('#paint2').get(0).addEventListener('touchstart', function(e) { paintRed(); }, false);

    //Change brush color to white 
    function erase(){
        color = "white";
    }

    //Change brush color to black 
    function paint(){
        color = "black";
    }

    //Change brush color to red 
    function paintRed(){
        color = "red";
    }


    //Make vias draggables.
    $via1.draggable({
        helper:'clone',
    });
    $via2.draggable({
        helper:'clone',
    });
    $via3.draggable({
        helper:'clone',
    });
    $via4.draggable({
        helper:'clone',
    });
    $via5.draggable({
        helper:'clone',
    });
    $via6.draggable({
        helper:'clone',
    });
    $via7.draggable({
        helper:'clone',
    });
    $via8.draggable({
        helper:'clone',
    });
    $via9.draggable({
        helper:'clone',
    });
    $via10.draggable({
        helper:'clone',
    });
    $via11.draggable({
        helper:'clone',
    });
    $via12.draggable({
        helper:'clone',
    });
    $via13.draggable({
        helper:'clone',
    });
    $via14.draggable({
        helper:'clone',
    });
    $via15.draggable({
        helper:'clone',
    });
    $via16.draggable({
        helper:'clone',
    });
    $via17.draggable({
        helper:'clone',
    });
    $via18.draggable({
        helper:'clone',
    });

    //Make icons draggables.

    $icon1.draggable({
        helper:'clone',
    });
    $icon2.draggable({
        helper:'clone',
    });
    $icon3.draggable({
        helper:'clone',
    });
    $icon4.draggable({
        helper:'clone',
    });
    $icon5.draggable({
        helper:'clone',
    });
    $icon6.draggable({
        helper:'clone',
    });
    $icon7.draggable({
        helper:'clone',
    });
    $icon8.draggable({
        helper:'clone',
    });
    $icon9.draggable({
        helper:'clone',
    });
    $icon10.draggable({
        helper:'clone',
    });
    $icon11.draggable({
        helper:'clone',
    });
    $icon12.draggable({
        helper:'clone',
    });
    $icon13.draggable({
        helper:'clone',
    });
    $icon14.draggable({
        helper:'clone',
    });
    $icon15.draggable({
        helper:'clone',
    });



    // set the data payload
    $via1.data("url","via1.png"); // key-value pair
    $via1.data("width","32"); // key-value pair
    $via1.data("height","33"); // key-value pair
    $via1.data("image",image1); // key-value pair
    $via2.data("url","via2.png"); // key-value pair
    $via2.data("width","32"); // key-value pair
    $via2.data("height","33"); // key-value pair
    $via2.data("image",image2); // key-value pair
    $via3.data("url","via3.png"); // key-value pair
    $via3.data("width","32"); // key-value pair
    $via3.data("height","33"); // key-value pair
    $via3.data("image",image3); // key-value pair
    $via4.data("url","via4.png"); // key-value pair
    $via4.data("width","32"); // key-value pair
    $via4.data("height","33"); // key-value pair
    $via4.data("image",image4); // key-value pair
    $via5.data("url","via5.png"); // key-value pair
    $via5.data("width","32"); // key-value pair
    $via5.data("height","33"); // key-value pair
    $via5.data("image",image5); // key-value pair
    $via6.data("url","via6.png"); // key-value pair
    $via6.data("width","32"); // key-value pair
    $via6.data("height","33"); // key-value pair
    $via6.data("image",image6); // key-value pair
    $via7.data("url","via7.png"); // key-value pair
    $via7.data("width","32"); // key-value pair
    $via7.data("height","33"); // key-value pair
    $via7.data("image",image7); // key-value pair
    $via8.data("url","via8.png"); // key-value pair
    $via8.data("width","32"); // key-value pair
    $via8.data("height","33"); // key-value pair
    $via8.data("image",image8); // key-value pair
    $via9.data("url","via9.png"); // key-value pair
    $via9.data("width","32"); // key-value pair
    $via9.data("height","33"); // key-value pair
    $via9.data("image",image9); // key-value pair
    $via10.data("url","via10.png"); // key-value pair
    $via10.data("width","32"); // key-value pair
    $via10.data("height","33"); // key-value pair
    $via10.data("image",image10); // key-value pair
    $via11.data("url","via11.png"); // key-value pair
    $via11.data("width","32"); // key-value pair
    $via11.data("height","33"); // key-value pair
    $via11.data("image",image11); // key-value pair
    $via12.data("url","via12.png"); // key-value pair
    $via12.data("width","32"); // key-value pair
    $via12.data("height","33"); // key-value pair
    $via12.data("image",image12); // key-value pair
    $via13.data("url","via13.png"); // key-value pair
    $via13.data("width","32"); // key-value pair
    $via13.data("height","33"); // key-value pair
    $via13.data("image",image13); // key-value pair
    $via14.data("url","via13.png"); // key-value pair
    $via14.data("width","32"); // key-value pair
    $via14.data("height","33"); // key-value pair
    $via14.data("image",image14); // key-value pair
    $via15.data("url","via15.png"); // key-value pair
    $via15.data("width","32"); // key-value pair
    $via15.data("height","33"); // key-value pair
    $via15.data("image",image15); // key-value pair
    $via16.data("url","via16.png"); // key-value pair
    $via16.data("width","32"); // key-value pair
    $via16.data("height","33"); // key-value pair
    $via16.data("image",image16); // key-value pair
    $via17.data("url","via17.png"); // key-value pair
    $via17.data("width","32"); // key-value pair
    $via17.data("height","33"); // key-value pair
    $via17.data("image",image17); // key-value pair
    $via18.data("url","via18.png"); // key-value pair
    $via18.data("width","32"); // key-value pair
    $via18.data("height","33"); // key-value pair
    $via18.data("image",image18); // key-value pair


   //Icons

    $icon1.data("url","icon1.png"); // key-value pair
    $icon1.data("width","32"); // key-value pair
    $icon1.data("height","33"); // key-value pair
    $icon1.data("image",imgicon1); // key-value pair
    $icon2.data("url","icon2.png"); // key-value pair
    $icon2.data("width","32"); // key-value pair
    $icon2.data("height","33"); // key-value pair
    $icon2.data("image",imgicon2); // key-value pair
    $icon3.data("url","icon3.png"); // key-value pair
    $icon3.data("width","32"); // key-value pair
    $icon3.data("height","33"); // key-value pair
    $icon3.data("image",imgicon3); // key-value pair
    $icon4.data("url","icon4.png"); // key-value pair
    $icon4.data("width","32"); // key-value pair
    $icon4.data("height","33"); // key-value pair
    $icon4.data("image",imgicon4); // key-value pair
    $icon5.data("url","icon5.png"); // key-value pair
    $icon5.data("width","32"); // key-value pair
    $icon5.data("height","33"); // key-value pair
    $icon5.data("image",imgicon5); // key-value pair
    $icon6.data("url","icon6.png"); // key-value pair
    $icon6.data("width","32"); // key-value pair
    $icon6.data("height","33"); // key-value pair
    $icon6.data("image",imgicon6); // key-value pair
    $icon7.data("url","icon7.png"); // key-value pair
    $icon7.data("width","32"); // key-value pair
    $icon7.data("height","33"); // key-value pair
    $icon7.data("image",imgicon7); // key-value pair
    $icon8.data("url","icon8.png"); // key-value pair
    $icon8.data("width","32"); // key-value pair
    $icon8.data("height","33"); // key-value pair
    $icon8.data("image",imgicon8); // key-value pair
    $icon9.data("url","icon9.png"); // key-value pair
    $icon9.data("width","32"); // key-value pair
    $icon9.data("height","33"); // key-value pair
    $icon9.data("image",imgicon9); // key-value pair
    $icon10.data("url","icon10.png"); // key-value pair
    $icon10.data("width","32"); // key-value pair
    $icon10.data("height","33"); // key-value pair
    $icon10.data("image",imgicon10); // key-value pair
    $icon11.data("url","icon11.png"); // key-value pair
    $icon11.data("width","32"); // key-value pair
    $icon11.data("height","33"); // key-value pair
    $icon11.data("image",imgicon11); // key-value pair
    $icon12.data("url","icon12.png"); // key-value pair
    $icon12.data("width","32"); // key-value pair
    $icon12.data("height","33"); // key-value pair
    $icon12.data("image",imgicon12); // key-value pair
    $icon13.data("url","icon13.png"); // key-value pair
    $icon13.data("width","32"); // key-value pair
    $icon13.data("height","33"); // key-value pair
    $icon13.data("image",imgicon13); // key-value pair
    $icon14.data("url","icon13.png"); // key-value pair
    $icon14.data("width","32"); // key-value pair
    $icon14.data("height","33"); // key-value pair
    $icon14.data("image",imgicon14); // key-value pair
    $icon15.data("url","icon15.png"); // key-value pair
    $icon15.data("width","32"); // key-value pair
    $icon15.data("height","33"); // key-value pair
    $icon15.data("image",imgicon15); // key-value pair
    // make the Kinetic Container a dropzone
    $stageContainer.droppable({
        drop:dragDrop,
    });

    // handle a drop into the Kinetic container
    function dragDrop(e,ui){
            // get the drop point
            var x = parseInt(ui.offset.left-offsetX);
            var y = parseInt(ui.offset.top-offsetY);

            // get the drop payload (here the payload is the image)
            var element=ui.draggable;
            var data=element.data("url");
            var theImage=element.data("image");

            // create a new Kinetic.Image at the drop point
            // be sure to adjust for any border width (here border==1)
            var image = new Kinetic.Image({
                name:data,
                x:x,
                y:y,
                image:theImage,
                draggable: true
            });
            layer.add(image);
            layer.draw();

    }

    //Remove the current backgraund and add a new
    function onReset() {
        background.remove();
        layer.add(background);
        layer.draw();
    }

    //Transform into image the current stage.
    function onSave(){
        stage.toDataURL({
          callback: function(dataUrl) {
            window.open(dataUrl,'Screenshot','toolbar=1,scrollbars=1,location=1,statusbar=0,menubar=0,resizable=1,width=800,height=600');
          }
        });
    }

    //Change the sizeDraw depending of the image clicked.
    function onSizeClick(size) {
        if(size == 'size1'){
            sizeDraw = 5;
        }
        else if(size == 'size2'){
            sizeDraw = 10;
        }
        else {
            sizeDraw = 20;
        }

    }

}
```

The code works fine on firefox and chrome, but the draggable part doesn't work on a mobile device. Anybody know how I can fix it?
And how can I do the program more structured?

Comment: Try http://touchpunch.furf.com/

Comment: I try, but doesn't work

Comment: Strange. I works for me on Android and iPad.

Comment: What I need to modify from my code ti add touchpunch?